# jenkins clone multiple repositories in different sub-directories

Tags: jenkins

I want to clone multiple repositories in different sub-directories in Jenkins. I am using standard git plugin, I can clone one repository in folder using "checkout to a sub-directory"

Here, I want to clone two repository in different directories

Comment: This was asked for in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-4535.  The suggestion there is to use the Multiple SCMs plugin.